# kohana 3.2 gets wrong session issue

Tags: session, kohana

case:

When using kohana driven site from 2 different devices I randomly get both session data on each device. I'm using native sessions to store few objects, but they should be private on each device. What am I doing wrong?

for example:

```
public function load()
{

    $session = Session::instance();
    $this->dialog = $session->get('dialog');

}

public function save()
{
    $session = Session::instance();
    $session->set('dialog', $this->dialog);
}
```

it looks like some kind of caching problem. I tried to regenerate session id every time. I've got 1st id, then 2nd, then 3rd and when i clicked a link a got 1st id again.

Comment: I guess this is a problem related to your PHP configuration. The Kohana native driver for sessions is really basic and I don't think it could cause this kind of problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure caching is turned off in your bootstrap file. And the cookie variables are set correctly, especially the `Cookie::$domain`.

Also verify your session config file too. You can find more info here: http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/sessions